# Converting .vrt to .tif causes massive change in coordinates

Tags: qgis, raster, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, vrt

[image: Original VRT (in color), -90 to 90, -180 to 180 coordinates.]

[image: Exported tif (grayscale), has values from 0 to 16800 and 43200 to 0.]

I am trying to convert a .vrt file to a .tif file so that I can upload it to Google Earth Engine as an image asset. However, I get an error that the tif is not within the -90 to 90 latitude range, causing an error when uploading.

After some investigation, I've found that for some reason, when I go to export the .vrt file to a .tif file, it changes the coordinates/dimensions of the image somehow even though everything is still technically in EPSG:4326. The grayscale (tif) coordinates end up having values going all the way to 16800 and 43200 instead of 90 and 180. (You can see the sample coordinates in the original color vrt vs the grayscale tif in the bottom left of each image.)

How do you convert the .vrt file to a .tif file in QGIS while maintaining the -90 to 90 and -180 to 180 bounding box so that I can upload it to GEE?

Comment: What corner coordinates does gdalinfo report with `gdalinfo your.vrt`?

Comment: For VRT:

Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-180.0000000,  83.9991672) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 83d59'57.00"N)
Lower Left  (-180.0000000, -56.0008104) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 56d 0' 2.92"S)
Upper Right ( 179.9999424,  83.9991672) (179d59'59.79"E, 83d59'57.00"N)
Lower Right ( 179.9999424, -56.0008104) (179d59'59.79"E, 56d 0' 2.92"S)
Center      (  -0.0000288,  13.9991784) (  0d 0' 0.10"W, 13d59'57.04"N)
Band 1 Block=128x128 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray

Comment: For .tif:
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (   0.0000000,   0.0000000) (  0d 0' 0.01"E,  0d 0' 0.01"N)
Lower Left  (       0.000,  -16800.000) (  0d 0' 0.01"E,Invalid angle)
Upper Right (   43200.000,       0.000) (Invalid angle,  0d 0' 0.01"N)
Lower Right (   43200.000,  -16800.000) (Invalid angle,Invalid angle)
Center      (   21600.000,   -8400.000) (Invalid angle,Invalid angle)

Comment: For some reason the .tif file has dropped the coordinate system totally and the reported coordinates are probably pixel coordinates. How did you do the conversion from .vrt into tif?

Comment: I just right clicked on the vrt file and exported as a tif (raw) in QGIS. What is the better way to do it?

Comment: If you add a basemap: the vrt file is correctly assigned geographically?